# How to do a fresh re-installation of Ubuntu safely on dual boot?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, uninstall

I have Ubuntu 13.04 and Windows 7 installed on different partitions. I want to do a fresh installation of Ubuntu 13.10 when it comes out. But for that I would have to remove Ubuntu 13.04. I want to know how to do that safely without running into a problem and repairing Windows 7 from USB or things like that.

**Please note that I am not using Wubi.**

Comment: Do you want to keep `/home`?

Comment: There is no need. All of my important files are kept in another partition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Ubuntu 13.10 becomes stable and released, then you can upgrade to 13.10 without the need of re-installing. You should see the message in update-manager when the upgrade becomes available.

If for your own reasons you want to re-install, then first you must create a Live USB with 13.10 (I prefer USB, you can create DVD if you want). After that, boot from the USB you've made and at the installer window probably you will see the option of `upgrade Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10` . Because the installer now is changing I cannot upload a picture of it because I don't know the final form. Either way the option of upgrade should exist.

Another way is through `something else` option. There you should know for sure the partition that you have installed Ubuntu 13.04, then click on this partition and then click `change`. Mount this partition to root (/) and proceed with the installation. You should click the `Format` box also, in order to have a clean installation of 13.10. Be aware that if you don't have a separate /home directory, all your personal files will be deleted.

[image]

[image]

In any of above ways you should not have any problem with Windows 7. Grub will be reinstalled and will recognize automatically the Windows 7 installation.

If for any reason you have a problem with grub (or grub menu) , use [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#A2nd_option_:_install_Boot-Repair_in_Ubuntu) to repair the grub.

Comment: I do not want to upgrade as it slows things down sometimes. So, will Windows just work perfectly if I install with "something else"?

Comment: I updated the answer :-)

Comment: Everything is all right but could you still let me know one thing, **how to uninstall it completely** (for any special reasons) *without hurting windows 7*?

Comment: In such case you should have a CD/DVD of Windows ready, or a repair CD/DVD is Ok, too. Because you will need to reinstall the bootloader of Windows after the removal of Ubuntu. In short, removing Ubuntu will remove grub also, so PC will not have any bootloader to boot. You have to re-install the bootloader of Windows in First HDD and all will be fine.